# Exchange Server 2010 send as another user and skip inbox

Tags: exchange-2010, email

We have Exchange Server 2010 setup and we can send email as another user.

However, we have an undesired side effect:

Authenticated as steve@domain.com, steve@domain.com can send an email to anyone as bill@domain.com, but the sent message ends up in bill's inbox, regardless of who the message was sent to.

Anyway we can disable this "feature" and not have the sent messages end up in the other user's inbox?

Here is a sample header:

```
Received: from localhost (xx.xx.xx.xx) by mail.domain.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) with
Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 14.1.289.1; Tue, 28 Jun 2011 12:37:53 -0700
From: Bill Gates <bill@domain.com>
To: Steve Jobs <steve@apple.com>
Reply-To: Bill Gates <bill@domain.com>
Subject: Test Subject
Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2011 12:37:52 -0700
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
Message-ID: <ff5f075d-e615-4e07-8527-395f05e006f2@EVAEXCH01.domain.local>
Return-Path: bill@domain.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: evaexch01.domain.local
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 06
X-Originating-IP: [xx.xx.xx.xx]
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: DR, OOF, AutoReply
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't believe that *is* standard behaviour.

Comment: I agree it does seem odd. However it does seem to be the default behavior.

Comment: I'm kinda clutching at straws here, but is there anything unusual in the message headers or in the message tracking logs to indicate what might be wrong?

Comment: How do the users connect to Exchange: POP, IMAP, MAPI? Do you use an SMTP proxy or smart host?

Comment: Thinking about it, there has *got to be* some other setting in play here. BlackBerry's use the `Send As` right so the BESAdmin account can send as the user - there's no way this wouldn't be *very* well documented if every time someone sent a message on their BlackBerry it also appeared in their Inbox. Have you got any weird transport rules enabled, or maybe message moderation on Steve's mailbox?

Comment: In addition, if I'm not mistaken there shouldn't be any headers for an internal message so the email has to be going outside the server and then back to Bill. Do the ip addresses in the headers give you a clue as to where the message is going?

Comment: Very good point - even after years of knowing internal messages don't have headers, I still find myself opening the window to view the headers. One of these days I will learn!

Comment: Good questions guys. When connection is established using MAPI, everything is fine. It is only when connecting using SMTP which is the problem, the connection is established via a PHP Script. We found for some reason, that steve's user did not have permission to email as himself. When that was corrected, the message does not go to his inbox.  Although now if you send on behalf joe, and steve as the reply to, steve still gets a copy in his inbox. Still working on resolving this last issue.

Comment: The original problem is likely relay access denied, which is why the PHP script cannot send. To fix that you either authenticate using PHP or set an exception on the receive connector for the IP address of the PHP server. Do the message tracking logs reveal anything useful?

Comment: random question, and maybe a bit silly to even asks but you don't have a forward all emails on from that mailbox do you back to bill? The result should be the sent item should be in Bill's sent folder rather then inbox. Message tracking might give you a few clues

Answer (score -1):

*Outdated to say the least....would have suggested to close it, but:*

The behavior is as expected and standard, but check [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2632409) to further clarify your request. Even though it describes the scenario to alter the default behavior, it will provide the necessary details to alter your scenario accordingly.

If not, please provide the necessary details and/or your solution and/or please close the incident

Comment: Inbox, not sent items.